# Query from Stored Javascript in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to store a query in mongodb's stored javascript, like so:

`$query = $collection->count(array( 'email' => "me@hotmail.com", 'app_id' => $app_id ));`

```
$db->system->js->save(array(
    "_id" => "archiveMessages2", 
    "value" => new MongoCode("function() { $query }")
));
```

And then I try running the query by executing the function like so:
`print_r($db->execute("archiveMessages2()"));`

But it doesn't return anything.

Please help

Comment: Hi, if I replace execute for evail I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method MongoDB::eval() in /var/www/dev/classes/EmailMessaging.php on line 26

Comment: Got it now, just needed to add 'return' like "value" => new MongoCode("function() { return $query }")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now, just needed to add 'return' like

`"value" => new MongoCode("function() { return $query }")`